# Regarding socket connection between host and docker container and host machine

Tags: docker, sockets, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to make a socket connection between my docker container and host machine. I am doing a embedded based project in a board which involves many functions. I had used one function using a docker container which was fetched from github repository ,and that function works correctly inside the container. But I couldn't take the output from that container outside of it to the board to enable a socket connection. The socket connection fails to execute inside the docker container. It is unable to make a communication from the docker container(client) to the server part which is outside the container. Kindly help me to sort this out.

Comment: Please, kindly provide more details of your setup. Also what is the question you are trying to ask?

Comment: What does that mean: "The socket connection fails to execute inside the docker container."? Show us what have you tried already.

Comment: @DevilaN I am doing a project on jetson nano . It includes many functions to carry out. I used one Github repository to fetch one application. It has downloaded as a docker container. That program works perfectly when running inside the container. I have also created a socket connection outside the docker container. Now I need to fetch the outputs generated from the docker container to the outside socket. My client is inside the docker container and server outside.  When running the client its not making connection with server. I need to send results to the server.